# Populating field values from DB as columns with data to View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following 2 tables:

This table contains the columns:
[image]

This table contains the values linked to those columns:
[image]

I want it in this format in my view:

[image]

Ive put it into an IENumerable which I am passing to the view via my model:

```
public class BudgetEntryNotesVM
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountDescription { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryVM> BudgetNoteLineEntryList { get; set; }

}

public class BudgetNoteLineEntryVM
{
    public int pkiNotesLineEntriesId { get; set; }
    public int fkiAccountId { get; set; }
    public string NotesColumnName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool isNewLineItem { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following to populate the data:

```
    public IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryVM> GetBudgetNoteLineEntry(int accId)
    {
        IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryVM> AccountsLineEntriesIList = new List<BudgetNoteLineEntryVM>();

        //var query2 =(from )

        var query = (from NC in _context.Notes_Columns
                     join NLE in _context.Notes_Line_Entries on NC.pkiNotesColumnsId equals NLE.fkiNotesColumnId
                     where NLE.fkiAccountId == accId
                     select new BudgetNoteLineEntryVM
                     {
                         pkiNotesLineEntriesId = NLE.pkiNotesLineEntriesId,
                         fkiAccountId = NLE.fkiAccountId,
                         NotesColumnName = NC.NotesColumnName,
                         Value = NLE.Value,
                         isNewLineItem = NLE.isNewEntry,
                         Sequence = NC.Sequence

                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n.Sequence);

        AccountsLineEntriesIList = query;

        return AccountsLineEntriesIList;
    }
```

And im populating it and passing it this way :

```
public ActionResult BudgetNoteLineEntry(int accId)
    {
        BudgetEntryNotesVM NVM = new BudgetEntryNotesVM();

        NVM.AccountNumber = _budgetEntryRepository.GetAccountName(accId);
        NVM.AccountDescription = _budgetEntryRepository.GetAccountDescription(accId);

        NVM.BudgetNoteLineEntryList = _budgetEntryRepository.GetBudgetNoteLineEntry(accId);

        return PartialView("_ShowAccountBudgetLineEntries", NVM);
    }
```

I simply can not think of a solution and I hope someone could lead me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have rather shown the 2 tables with the data that I am pulling from. The link between the two is the fkiNotesColumnId - Id believe this is the field that identifies which values belong to which column ? Hope this helps a bit more ?

Comment: @AxleWack you can make a 2-dimensional array in which all the data will be sorted and render it separately from headers taken from first table. `ViewModel` should contain already formatted data.

Comment: I will look into it and give it a try. Thanks Andrey

Comment: Thanks Stephen - This seems more in the lines that I would prefer to go, only problem is the properties 'Grade', 'BasicPay', 'OverTime' etc. are not static fields, these could be anything the user chooses. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen. It can be less or more. I have currently put in 8 columns - it all depends on how many columns the user would want. It could be 3, or 5 or 10, it is all up to the user. I have posted code below and was able to get it working by making use of a 2D array. Im sure there is a better way of doing it, but this worked for me for the moment

Comment: I feel the same way :) But needed to get it working and couldnt think of another way :( Ill await your answer, and hopefully it can make things simpler :) Thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequences of 8 entries with no skipped numbers you could do something like this

Your data entity may look like

```
public class TableEntry
{
    public int pkiNotesLineEntriesId { get; set; }
    public int fkiAccountId { get; set; }
    public int fkiNotesColumnId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool isNewEntry { get; set; }
}
```

So you can divide your table data into a List of arrays:

```
List<TableEntry[]> desiredFormat = new List<TableEntry[]>();

int pages = entries.Count() / 8;
for (int page = 0; page < pages; page++)
{
    TableEntry[] row = entries.OrderBy(e => e.pkiNotesLineEntriesId).Skip(page * 8).Take(8).ToArray();
    desiredFormat.Add(row);
}
```

Then pass it to your view with an array of headers and render them separately to a table.

If it has no certain size you can use this

```
int maxSize = entries.Max(c => c.fkiNotesColumnId);
TableEntry[] row = new TableEntry[maxSize];
int current = 0;
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    if (entry.fkiNotesColumnId < current)
    {
        desiredFormat.Add(row);
        row = new TableEntry[maxSize];
        current = 0;
    }
    row[entry.fkiNotesColumnId - 1] = entry;
    current = entry.fkiNotesColumnId;
}
```

Comment: It could be more or it could be less than 8, but the sequence should always run in order. I am completely out of ideas, so please share more info and I will try look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately the above wouldnt work properly, because the ordering of the fkiNotesColumnId could differ, depending on the sequence of the Columns. However, you did lead me in the right direction by making use of a 2D Array! So I thank you for that! I will post my code for all to see.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from Andrey, I made use of a 2D array. The way I did it is perhaps not the best way out there, but it worked:

View Model:

```
public class BudgetEntryNotesVM
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountDescription { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryVM> BudgetNoteLineEntryList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsVM> BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsList { get; set; }
    public string[,] BudgetLineEntryArray { get; set; }
}
```

Functions in my repository(Same as a class containing all my functions):

```
//Getting Columns to populate table in PartialView
    public IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsVM> GetBudgetNoteEntryLineColumns(int accId)
    {
        IEnumerable<BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsVM> AccountsLineEntriesColumnIList = new List<BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsVM>();

        //var query2 =(from )

        var query = (from NC in _context.Notes_Columns
                     join NLE in _context.Notes_Line_Entries on NC.pkiNotesColumnsId equals NLE.fkiNotesColumnId
                     where NLE.fkiAccountId == accId
                     select new BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsVM
                     {
                         Sequence = NC.Sequence,
                         ColumnName = NC.NotesColumnName

                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(n=>n.Sequence);

        AccountsLineEntriesColumnIList = query;

        return AccountsLineEntriesColumnIList;
    }

//Getting data to populate table
    public string[,] GetBudgetNoteLineEntry(int accId)
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        //Getting total number of rows based on the EntryLineId
        var outer = (from NC in _context.Notes_Columns
                     join NLE in _context.Notes_Line_Entries on NC.pkiNotesColumnsId equals NLE.fkiNotesColumnId
                     where NLE.fkiAccountId == accId
                     select NLE.EntryLineId).Distinct().Count();

        //Getting total number of columns based on the Account ID
        var inner = (from NC in _context.Notes_Columns
                     join NLE in _context.Notes_Line_Entries on NC.pkiNotesColumnsId equals NLE.fkiNotesColumnId
                     where NLE.fkiAccountId == accId
                     select NC.NotesColumnName).Distinct().Count();

        //Declaring 2D Array with Inner and Outer values above
        string[,] entrylines = new string[outer, inner];

        //Getting all data in order of the Columns
        var query = (from NC in _context.Notes_Columns
                     join NLE in _context.Notes_Line_Entries on NC.pkiNotesColumnsId equals NLE.fkiNotesColumnId
                     where NLE.fkiAccountId == accId
                     select new BudgetNoteLineEntryVM
                     {
                         pkiNotesLineEntriesId = NLE.pkiNotesLineEntriesId,
                         fkiAccountId = NLE.fkiAccountId,
                         NotesColumnName = NC.NotesColumnName,
                         Value = NLE.Value,
                         isNewLineItem = NLE.isNewEntry,
                         Sequence = NC.Sequence,
                         EntryLineId = NLE.EntryLineId

                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n.Sequence).ThenBy(n=>n.EntryLineId);

        //Looping through every item and adding to 2D array based on the ordering of the columns
        foreach(var item in query)
        {
            if(row >= outer)
            {
                row = 0;
                column++;
            }

            entrylines[row, column] = item.Value;

            if (row <= outer)
            {
                row++;
            }

        }

        return entrylines;
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult BudgetNoteLineEntry(int accId)
    {
        BudgetEntryNotesVM NVM = new BudgetEntryNotesVM();

        NVM.AccountNumber = _budgetEntryRepository.GetAccountName(accId);
        NVM.AccountDescription = _budgetEntryRepository.GetAccountDescription(accId);

        NVM.BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsList = _budgetEntryRepository.GetBudgetNoteEntryLineColumns(accId);
        //NVM.BudgetNoteLineEntryList = _budgetEntryRepository.GetBudgetNoteLineEntry(accId);
        NVM.BudgetLineEntryArray = _budgetEntryRepository.GetBudgetNoteLineEntry(accId);

        return PartialView("_ShowAccountBudgetLineEntries", NVM);
    }
```

My View:

```
@model BudgetEntryNotesVM

<div id="listofBudgetEntries">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Note Line Entries</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
                        <tr style="background-color: #00b8ce; color: white;">
                            @foreach (var hlitem in Model.BudgetNoteLineEntryColumnsList)
                            {
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelhitem => hlitem.ColumnName)
                                </th>


                            }
                        </tr>

                        @for (int row = 0; row <= Model.BudgetLineEntryArray.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                @for (int column = 0; column <= Model.BudgetLineEntryArray.GetUpperBound(1); column++)
                                {
                                    <td>@Model.BudgetLineEntryArray[row, column]</td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this is pretty custom to what I need, but perhaps this can help someone else with an idea, if they are looking at doing the same thing. I do still think there is a better way of doing this, but ive struggled too long on this to find that better solution.

Andrey, again, thanks for leading me into the right direction.